# simulation environment of underwater robot

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I wang to build a simulation environment of underwater robot(or AUV) to test my SLAM algorithms, but many things in ROS  can't be found, such as sonar. I konw UWSIM, but there is something is wrong while installing it.

Any good suggestions?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/251692/simulation-environment-of-underwater-robot/) by [niubc](https://answers.ros.org/users/27846/niubc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 75 on 2017-01-10

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [murdock](https://answers.ros.org/users/26483/murdock/) on 2019-02-22**:
Have you ever managed to implement SLAM for AUVs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, you could try the [UUV Simulator](https://github.com/uuvsimulator/uuv_simulator) package. I am working now on making more realistic simulation of the sensors, but controllers and vehicle models are already available.

---

Originally posted by [Musa Marcusso](https://answers.ros.org/users/32182/musa-marcusso/) with karma: 81 on 2018-07-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here there are some repos for underwater simulation and development.

- [COLA2](https://iquarobotics.com/cola2): ROS and Gazebo
- [VRX](https://github.com/osrf/vrx): ROS and Gazebo
- [UUV Simulator](https://uuvsimulator.github.io/): ROS and Gazebo
- [Plankton](https://github.com/Liquid-ai/Plankton): ROS2 and Gazebo
- [Ignition native underwater vehicles](https://ignitionrobotics.org/api/gazebo/5.0/underwater_vehicles.html): Ignition
- [UW Vehicle Simulated in Ignition](https://github.com/osrf/lrauv/): Ignition
- [Project Dave](https://github.com/Field-Robotics-Lab/dave/wiki): ROS and Gazebo
- [DS SIM](https://bitbucket.org/whoidsl/ds_sim/src/master/): ROS and Gazebo
- [Hydrographic Messages](https://github.com/apl-ocean-engineering/hydrographic_msgs): ROS

Check this link if you are interested in helping the community developing open maritime robotics software:
https://discourse.ros.org/t/new-working-group-proposal-maritime-robotics/23832

---

Originally posted by [matosinho](https://answers.ros.org/users/47762/matosinho/) with karma: 61 on 2022-01-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3